# TypeScript map interface to literal type

Tags: typescript

Lets say I have a following interface that represents some filter settings:

```
interface IFilterSettings {
  title: string,
  teamMembers: Members
}
```

However, my filter can emit change for a single field only. How can I achieve deriving following type from `IFilterSettings`?:

```
type FilterChange = {field: 'title', payload: string} | { field: 'teamMembers', payload: Members };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core feature you need to use is [Distributive Conditional Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types). It allows to construct new union type from another union type.

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIQLYCNoGdkDeAUMqcrgPYYQBiwEANgCYBcyAriANYgUDuIIgF8iRUJFiIUASToMJAZQhgwoAOb5iZZKrAMIbXGCjqANCTKQ4GdNjxtbOKLmGiwATwAOKORIDynqoUIAA8ANIQ7sgQAB6QIEz4XJEUMMgAanAM7BCmGVk5AHzIALzIEVGx8YnIcCDuFqQA-ITIMPTMbBV5nnDuDBRwrPnZEADaFQC6yCLabCAQAG7QANxuXj7A8tAAwgAWdWq0UFRKKuq4IWeqIBrFZb7QAUGhye6pyNcXeV+3uIXrbzIR5QfaHFAPLYSMG3Y6nZQ3DQhWRQ6C-O5rIgIYJGHQARjYIJhRxoJww6MuKO2UAp90IjTaHWGACJdPpmeZtL1+oMWRzXFicWAdAAmQmo0EHWGk+HnP7IkG00r07TtRgsqw2TBOXD8rl9AZDNgEchUWhMtjM5kzcwiIA)

```js
interface Members {
    someField: unknown
}

interface IFilterSettings {
    title: string,
    teamMembers: Members
}

//  `Key extends any` is always true, but we need it to enable distributive conditional type
type FilterOption<Key extends keyof Value, Value> = Key extends any
    // here we convert key to desired format
    ? { field: Key, payload: Value[Key] }
    : never;

// If we try to use this variant, we end up with
// type FilterChange = { field: "title" | "teamMembers", payload: string | Members }
/*
type FilterOption<Key extends keyof Value, Value> = { field: Key, payload: Value[Key] }
*/

// Here we use `keyof Settings` to create initial union of all keys
type FilterChangeFromSettings<Settings> = FilterOption<keyof Settings, Settings>

type FilterChange = FilterChangeFromSettings<IFilterSettings>;
```

Comment: Great! Missed this one. Thank you :-)